Clock feedthrough of the bootstrapped switch
I'm learning about the bootstrapped switch through this paper. Razavi used a 20 µm / 28 nm NMOS (M1) as the main switch to achieve low Ron. I am wondering does this wide device cause any problem because of clock feedthrough? In addition, what are the key considerations when sizing the bootstrapped switch?

